# Deleteing entites/objects from the "Data store" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have been debugging an app in eclipse/jetty, and it has a bunch of invalid objects. How do i clear them out? Where are the data entities actually stored when running on your local machine??

Comment: Could you please provide examples for 'invalid objects'? Actually the question is pretty unclear (at least to me)

Comment: I didn't detail because it was irrelivant, but for the record, I had to change a `String` field to a `Text` field and couldn't work out how to either convert it or clear out the old data.

Comment: if you just want to convert entities from one "schema" to another, you can load the entities up using the low level API, change the field, then save the entity again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to delete the whole (local) datastore, delete this file:
  `./WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin`.

Or, you can delete specific objects with delete calls from JDO/JPA/whatever datastore api you are using.

As a third alternative, you can try viewing your data using the admin viewer:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
```

Since "invalid objects" is kind of vague, you'll have to decide which of these options works best for you.